# sqlite converting a row result to column for listview android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview, row

I would like to display a query result (row) into a ListView  (Column) with a single table. I am not sure how to do this. I was thinking of doing it with a for loop but didnt not work. Could someone help me please. I am working with 1 table.

Here is my table sample:

table name: ruling

number of columns: 75

regular search will display like this: (select * from ruling where name = charlie)

Note: the numbers are not number but block of text(full sentence / paragraph) 
table: ruling

```
 name        r1     r2     r3     r4     r5    ...... r75
 -------     --     --     --     --     --    ...... ---
 charlie      1      2      3      4      5    ...... 75
```

I want to display is the following result

```
charlie
1
2
3
4
5   
.
.
.
75
```

The reason is that with the result I want to capture it into a listView and I am not sure how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the pseudo code.

Implement this function in your db helper class.

```
public ArrayList<String> getRow(String name) {
ArrayList<String> row= new ArrayList<String>();
String query = "SELECT * FROM ruling where name=name";
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] { "1" });

 if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    row.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(r1));
    row.add(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(r2));
    ....
    ....
    }
return row;
}
```

Use this arraylist as source in your custom adapter for listview.

Hope this helps.